# How to implement ufunc 'matmul' using Numpy-C API?

Tags: numpy, python-c-api, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

I am trying to implement a custom datatype with built-in support for numpy using Numpy-C API.
My code is based on the quaterion implementation by https://github.com/moble/quaternion.
Currently that project has supported functions like 'add', 'multiply', 'divide', 'power'.

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(2, 2).astype(np.quaternion)
>>> a
array([[quaternion(0.135325974754691, 0, 0, 0),
        quaternion(0.536005227432872, 0, 0, 0)],
       [quaternion(0.86691238892986, 0, 0, 0),
        quaternion(0.306838076780839, 0, 0, 0)]], dtype=quaternion)
>>> a * a # multiply per element
array([[quaternion(0.0183131194433073, 0, 0, 0),
        quaternion(0.287301603835365, 0, 0, 0)],
       [quaternion(0.751537090080076, 0, 0, 0),
        quaternion(0.0941496053625638, 0, 0, 0)]], dtype=quaternion)
```

But found it really difficult to support matmul (@) using Numpy C API. And the quaternion project does not support the matmul ufunc:

```
>>> a @ a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'matmul' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Is there any Demo code or Document that can help me to write support for `np.matmul`?

Comment: The `@` delegates to `arr.__matmul__`.  All operators delegate to a `.__....` method.  I don't know exactly what the relation is between the `ufunc` `np.matmul` and this method.  Both are compiled.  But for quaternion what do you expect `matmul` to do.  I'm a little rusty on those, what's quaternion "matrix product"?  You are aware, aren't you that `(x * y).sum(axis=1)` does the matrix product for suitably aligned arrays?

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. I am trying to implement my own datatype which accounts on matmul pretty much, and my code is based on the quaternion implementation. I am not sure what you mean by suitably aligned but I believe matmul is something like ``[i,j] = sum(x[i, :] * y[:, j])``. Is there a easier way to replace matmul with multiply and sum without looping on ``i`` and ``j``?